# Inspecting data prior to SSL/TLS Encryption on a Android Device

Tags: android, linux, ssl

Is it possible to get the network packets / stream prior to encryption? I mean if you are locally root and could compile pretty much everything yourself, even the kernel. Where would be the best place to do it, if it's even possible?

Somewhere inside the android framework might be a good point, where the encryption is actually done.

I know about all the mitm ways to attack, but it would be great if there would be a way without using a "proxy" or any other default gateway.

It would be used for debugging purposes on a special developer device.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the source code of Android but I know that it  uses OpenSSL. You might try to hook into the SSL_read and SSL_write functions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks! This seems to be what I've been looking for. I'll try to see if the traffic takes this path. Hope it will work.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich These methods are actually used in android, i see some traffic there. Thanks for the great hint!

Comment: There's a lot going on with SSL_read and SSL_write, that worked well, thanks. But I still don't see all the data that enters/leaves the device encrypted. Are there any other SSL_... methods that might be used for payload traffic?

Comment: Is there any https get method in openSSL which might allow to fetch files from certain https:// urls during an SSL-Session? Somehow I see the urls built and negotiated, but I do not see the payload.

Comment: OpenSSL does not do HTTPS, which is HTTP inside TLS. It only cares about the TLS part, no matter what kind of data you wrap in TLS.

Comment: Apart from SSL_(read|write) there are also various [BIO_* methods](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html) which are a layer below the SSL_(read|write) methods. Some apps might use these directly instead of the SSL layer methods. But unfortunately BIO_read and BIO_write are also used without SSL data, so it is not that easy to simple put a hook their.